# Discover and fix the memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to find the memory leak in the example [here](http://debuggingmemoryleaks.eu01.aws.af.cm/example/11):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindTabs);

function bindTabs(){
    var lastTab,
        tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs li"),
        i;

    function selectTab(){
        activateTab(this);
        loadContent(this.attributes["data-load"].value);
    }

    function activateTab(tab){
        if (lastTab) {
            lastTab.classList.remove("active");
        }
        (lastTab = tab).classList.add("active");
    }

    [].forEach.call(tabs, function(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', selectTab, false);
    });
}


function loadContent(url){
    getContent(url).then(function(data){
        prepareContent(data);
        prepareGallery();
    })
}

var lastDiv;
function prepareContent(data){
    var content = document.getElementById("content"),
        div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = data;
    if (lastDiv) {
        content.removeChild(lastDiv);
    }
    content.appendChild(div);
    lastDiv = div;
}

function prepareGallery(){
    var width = 426,
        forward = false,
        position = 0,
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery li"),
        number = elements.length;

    function checkDirection() {
        if (position === 0) {
            forward = true;
        } else if (position === (number  - 1)) {
            forward = false;
        }
    }

    function changeLeftProperty() {
        var value = (-1 * width * position) + "px";
        [].forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
          el.style.left = value;
        });
    }

    function advance(){
        position = position + (forward ? 1 : -1);
    }

    function move(){
        checkDirection();
        advance();
        changeLeftProperty();
    }
    setInterval(move, 2000);
}

function getContent(url){
    var callbacks = [],
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e){
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            callbacks.forEach(function(cb){
                cb(xhr.response);
            })
        }
    }
    xhr.send()
    return {
        then: function(fn){
            callbacks.push(fn)
        }
    }
}
```

I profiled the page by taking heap snapshots and running the timeline but unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything.

Can you suggest me where could be the problem and what is the exact memory leak (if any)?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code in the question rather than just linking to it. There's no guarantee that the link will always be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `setInterval(move, 2000);` in `prepareGallery` that will be called every click, and there is no `clearInterval`.

Comment: So the list elements `.gallery li` (and not only) leak, right?

Comment: I have made the change and there is no more leak :) `if(x)
clearInterval(x); x = setInterval(move, 2000)` . Nice catch :)

Comment: A copy of `prepareGallery` with its property (`elements`, function definitions ecc) will be in memory each click.